# Why a project from maven-archetype-webapp in intelij idea is not created?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, maven-archetype

I'm trying to create a new project in intelij idea using maven-archetype-webapp, but the following error occurs during compilation

[image: Creating the project...]

[image: All settings of project]

[image: Error]

[image: Error2]

[image: Error3]

[image: Error4]

Full text version of the error

```
C:\Users\Artem\.jdks\liberica-1.8.0_345\bin\java.exe -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Users\Artem\AppData\Local\Temp\archetypetmp -Djansi.passthrough=true -Dmaven.home=C:\Users\Artem\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\231.9225.16\plugins\maven\lib\maven3 -Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Users\Artem\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\231.9225.16\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf -Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\Users\Artem\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\231.9225.16\plugins\maven\lib\maven-event-listener.jar -javaagent:C:\Users\Artem\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\231.9225.16\lib\idea_rt.jar=58796:C:\Users\Artem\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\231.9225.16\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\Artem\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\231.9225.16\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\Artem\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\231.9225.16\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds.license org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2023.1.4 -DinteractiveMode=false -DgroupId=com.artem.spring.mvc -DartifactId=springMVCCourse -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DarchetypeVersion=1.0 org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:RELEASE:generate
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< org.apache.maven:standalone-pom >-------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:3.2.1:generate (default-cli) > generate-sources @ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:3.2.1:generate (default-cli) < generate-sources @ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:3.2.1:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Generating project in Batch mode
[WARNING] No archetype found in remote catalog. Defaulting to internal catalog
[INFO] Archetype repository not defined. Using the one from [org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:1.0] found in catalog internal
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetypes/maven-archetype-webapp/1.0/maven-archetype-webapp-1.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.126 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-07-21T21:09:43+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.2.1:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:1.0) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What can be the error, is there any other way to create a project with maven-archetype-webapp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to wait and try again later, the problem may have been in the Internet connection or the server was not responding